# ASP.NET AJAX $find method failes when used in jQuery's $(document).ready() method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to find a tree using ASP.NET AJAX's client-side framework. I also use jQuery for doing any JavaScript operation after the DOM is ready. my code is like:

```
$(function(){
    var tree = $find('treeId');
});
```

Here, tree simply is null. But when I try to find the tree on click of one of elements, it's not null:

```
$(function(){
    $('saveButton').click(function(){
        var tree = $find('treeId');
    }):
});
```

Comment: Is `treeId` in the markup code or is it loaded later via JavaScript somehow? Can you find any other id in the `ready`-function?

Comment: Yeah, `treeId` is the Id of my tree (anything that has been set on the server, and it's static). It's true Id is 'pagesTree'.

Comment: @Dynamicus, @user811785, yes, that's what I meant. "Is the control with id `treeId` in the static structure and not loaded dynamically". Perhaps I wasn't that clear..

Comment: yes, of course, it's in the static structure of the page (defined in the markup and not fetched through AJAX).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this worked for me with Telerik controls:

```
$telerik.$(document).ready(function () {
    var tree = $telerik.$find("<%=RadTreeView1.ClientID%>");
});
```

see this http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-using-jquery.html

Comment: No, $('#treeId') returns a jQuery object. I need an ASP.NET AJAX's object. $find('treeId') returns an strongly-typed object that can be used to further manipulate the ASP.NET's tree.

Comment: Tried that, but no result. I use ASP.NET 4 ClientIDMode set to static. So, technically, there is no need to use inline ASP.NET. I can hardcode the Id of tree like: `$find('pagesTree')`

Comment: do you have a jQuery reference in your mark-up? Afaik some Telerik controls include it already hence they might conflict.

Comment: Yeah, I also have another jQuery reference to be loaded separately. But when I removed it, still I had the problem. Anyway, good point. Thank you

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much. You cured a long headache of mine :). The point is, when you include jQuery besides Telerik's jQuery, you should reference them in two different ways. jQuery with `$`, and Telerik's jQuery with `$telerik.$`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using ASP.NET Ajax DOM Ready.

```
Sys.onReady(function() {
    //DOM is ready to access and use
    var tree = $find('treeId');
});
```

Comment: I did that, but no use. Actually, I'm using Telerik RadTree and it seems that it's not injecting Sys into the page.

Comment: @user811785: i am sorry. i haven't used rad controls. why dont you try the forum they have?

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems with the telerik controls and `ClientIDMode="Static"` before. I simply removed this attribute and used `$find('<%= Radtree1.ClientID %>')` and it worked.

Edit:
Following on from the accepted answer, you can set the default $ to use jquery by pointing it to the telerik $.

window.$ = $telerik.$

If you do that on the site.master (or anywhere global) you'll be able to use jquery as normal.

Comment: Well, I also tried that. Still no result. I think there should be no difference between the way we write server-side code. Because what matters is that the inline ASP.NET would be executed and a string would be sent to the browser.