# $find returning null

Tags: asp.net

I have radGrid in `.ascx` page in which I want to find the control using `$find` but it returns a null to me. Below is my code which I am using to get the object (written in .ascx).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var Rates_gridID = $find('<%= gridRates.ClientID %>');
        alert(Rates_gridID);
    });
</script>
```

Here, I am getting `Rates_gridID` as null in alert. Interesting thing which I noted is when I change the jQuery version to `1.2.6` from `1.6.4` I am getting `Rates_gridID` object. I have googled this a lot but not getting any solution. I think the problem is with `$(function()`.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452881/asp-net-ajax-find-method-failes-when-used-in-jquerys-document-ready-metho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the incorrect syntax. Try

```
$("body").find('<%= gridRates.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: @ShreeKhanal, Pravu!.. darshan

Answer (score 3):

`$find` is differ from `$.find`.
The first one is provides a shortcut to the `findComponent` method of the `Sys.Application` class which defined by the Microsoft AJAX Library.
while the second is API method from jQuery which get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

So, `$find` has to find Component not html DOM. and ajax Library has to be defined.

For more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397441(v=vs.100).aspx
http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Thanks, finally someone mentioned the shortcut to Sys.Application

Answer (score 1):

what is `$find` here . it is incorrect.

use it like

```
$("body").find('<%= gridRates.ClientID %>');
```

see more about `find()` in

http://api.jquery.com/find/

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element

Answer (score -1):

If <%=gridRates.ClientID%> is unique id you should use like this

```
var Rates_gridID = $("#<%=gridRates.ClientID%>");
alert(Rates_gridID);
```