# JQuery and ASP.Net Ajax conflicts?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm wondering if there are any common or known conflicts/workarounds for working with both jquery and ASP.Net ajax.  Specifically, there seems to be some issues when using JQuery's `wrapinner` method and then later making a call to .Net's `$find` method.

This is a general idea of the markup I'm using.  It's a pretty complex layout so I trimmed it down for the most part.  Sorry it's so dense.  The error is occurring in the resizePage function.

**OUTER PAGE**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
    <telerik:radsplitter id="rsMain" runat="server" orientation="Vertical" height="100%"
        width="100%" bordersize="0" panesbordersize="0" resizewithbrowserwindow="true">
        <telerik:radpane id="rpCentral" runat="server" scrolling="None">
        <div id="wrapper" style="padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0;">
            <iframe name="left_frame" src="test.aspx" runat="server" id="left_frame" width="100%"
            frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
        </telerik:radpane>
        <telerik:radsplitbar id="rsbRHS" runat="server" collapsemode="Backward">
        </telerik:radsplitbar>
        <telerik:radpane id="rpRHS" runat="server" width="30%" minwidth="50" minheight="50">
        <iframe name="right_frame" src="field_description.aspx" width="100%" frameborder="0"
            marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="100%" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
        </telerik:radpane>
    </telerik:radsplitter>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ResizePage() {
            var width = widthPCT * jQuery(window).width();
            var panel = $find('<%= rpRHS.ClientID %>');

            var collapsed = panel._isCollapsed();

            $find('<%= rpRHS.ClientID %>').Expand();
            $find('<%= rpRHS.ClientID %>').set_width(width);

            if (collapsed)
                $find('<%= rpRHS.ClientID %>').Collapse();
        };

        function AddScrolling() {
            var body = GetFrameBody();


            if (body.length == 0) {
                setTimeout("AddScrolling()", 500);
                return;
            }

            jQuery(body).wrapInner("<div id='reportwrapper' style='overflow: auto; position: relative;'></div>");
            jQuery(body).css("background-color", "red");

            ResizePage();
        }

        $.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            AddScrolling();
        });

        jQuery(window).resize(function () {
            setTimeout(ResizePage, 100);
        });    
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**INNER PAGE**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:radscriptmanager id="scriptManager" runat="server" />
    <div>
        <div id="inner" style="height: 2000px; width: 2000px">
          Some Text
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try document.getElementById('<%= rpRHS.ClientID %>') and see what value that comes up with.

Comment: And when you look at the source of the rendered page can you see the control ID?

Comment: @zeroef The ClientID turns out to actually just be rpRHS so that shouldn't be creating any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can put jQuery into noConflict mode like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

I had to do the same on a page I was using Ajax on.

**UPDATE:** I noticed you were using telerik controls so I did some searching and came up with this:

[ASP.NET AJAX $find method failes when used in jQuery's $(document).ready() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452881/asp-net-ajax-find-method-failes-when-used-in-jquerys-document-ready-metho).

That Stackoverflow question/answer might help out.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  I implemented this and $find is still returning null where jQuery and $get are returning objects.

Comment: @mrK have you tried with just the ajax to make sure it is a conflict issue?

Comment: if I comment out the line containing the .wrapinner, everything works fine (other than not having the div I need)

Comment: I posted my code, sorry it's so dense.  I tried to trim it down as much as possible while leaving the important parts.

Comment: I tried that yesterday but $ telerik.$ find didn't exist.  I think that might be related to it being a newt version but I'll look into that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any literature on $telerik.$find being an actual thing.  Do you know anything about it?

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery splitter instead of rad

http://methvin.com/splitter/